Storing Duration in spreadsheet
What is the ideal way to store duration datatype of polars in a spreadsheet, as it is getting converted on its own, and I do not get the data like “1d 2m” when I export to spreadsheet?
Convert
1d 2m
2h 1m
To either a string or a time format

What currently happens? Are you experiencing https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7174

Yes, I currently convert it to a string which gives a number probably in number of microseconds. And when I cast it to pl.Time, I dont get the days info.

Update: .dt.to_string() support for Duration types was added in Polars 1.14.0
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("duration").dt.to_string(format="polars")
      .name.suffix("_str")
)

shape: (1, 2)
┌───────────────────┬───────────────────┐
│ duration          ┆ duration_str      │
│ ---               ┆ ---               │
│ duration[μs]      ┆ str               │
╞═══════════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 1d 2m 3s 987654µs ┆ 1d 2m 3s 987654µs │
└───────────────────┴───────────────────┘


Original answer
There is an open feature request for keeping the Duration format when casted to String:

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7174

df = pl.select(duration = pl.duration(days=1, seconds=123, microseconds=987654))

df.with_columns(duration_string = pl.col("duration").cast(str))

shape: (1, 2)
┌───────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ duration          ┆ duration_string │
│ ---               ┆ ---             │
│ duration[μs]      ┆ str             │
╞═══════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1d 2m 3s 987654µs ┆ 86523987654     │
└───────────────────┴─────────────────┘

The code for the frame repr formatting is here:

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/crates/polars-core/src/fmt.rs#L893

It is possible to attempt to port it to Polars expressions.
Probably not something one would use, but may serve as an interesting example of what is possible with expressions.
def duration_to_string(col, time_unit="us"):
    names = ["d", "h", "m", "s"]
    
    sizes = {
        "us": [864e8,  36e8,  6e7,  1e6],
        "ns": [864e11, 36e11, 6e10, 1e9],
        "ms": [864e5,  36e5,  6e4,  1e3]
    }[time_unit]
    
    remainder = {
        "us": 
            (pl.when(col % 1e3 != 0).then(pl.format("{}µs", (col % 1e6).cast(int)))
               .when(col % 1e6 != 0).then(pl.format("{}ms", ((col % 1e6) / 1e3).cast(int)))),
        "ns": 
            (pl.when(col % 1e3 != 0).then(pl.format("{}ns", (col % 1e9).cast(int)))
               .when(col % 1e6 != 0).then(pl.format("{}µs", ((col % 1e9) / 1e3).cast(int)))
               .when(col % 1e9 != 0).then(pl.format("{}ms", ((col % 1e9) / 1e6).cast(int)))),
        "ms":
            (pl.when(col % 1e3 != 0).then(pl.format("{}ms", (col % 1e3).cast(int))))
    }[time_unit]

    blank, space = pl.lit(""), pl.lit(" ")
    
    def build_fmt(name, whole_num, size):
        valid = (whole_num <= -1) | (whole_num >= 1)
        pad = pl.when(col % size != 0).then(space).otherwise(blank)
        fmt = pl.format("{}{}{}", whole_num.cast(int), pl.lit(name), space)
        return pl.when(valid).then(fmt).otherwise(blank)
        
    size = sizes[0]
    whole_num = col / sizes[0]
    expr = build_fmt(names[0], whole_num, size)
    
    for i in range(1, 4):
        size = sizes[i]
        whole_num = (col % sizes[i - 1]) / size
        expr += build_fmt(names[i], whole_num, size)
    
    expr += remainder.otherwise(blank)
                 
    return (
         pl.when(col == 0)
           .then(pl.lit("0" + time_unit.replace("u", "µ")))
           .otherwise(expr)
    )

And call it with Expr.pipe()
df.with_columns(
   pl.col("duration").pipe(duration_to_string, time_unit=df.schema["duration"].time_unit)
     .name.suffix("_string")
)

shape: (1, 2)
┌───────────────────┬───────────────────┐
│ duration          ┆ duration_string   │
│ ---               ┆ ---               │
│ duration[μs]      ┆ str               │
╞═══════════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 1d 2m 3s 987654µs ┆ 1d 2m 3s 987654µs │
└───────────────────┴───────────────────┘


I think a better version of this would be if we convert it to time, and for days we add 24 to the hours, something like this, 1d 1h 1m 1s -> 25:01:01
